# Better way to design a web application with data persistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-applications, websocket

For my Web apps I'm always wondering, which way is the best to design a proper Web applications with data persistance. For now I design every time a single HTML page, and all the content and the data upload is managed with jQuery AJAX requests based on a RESTful model, to a remote server which takes care of the database. But at the end that make sometimes a lot of AJAX calls, and getting huge amount of data takes sometimes a few seconds, which is not user-friendly.

Is there something like a guideline, or a standard way of developing to design web App ?

I've already looked over the WebWorkers and WebSockets Javascript API, but never used them yet. Does anybody already try it ? Does that allows better performance than AJAX exchanges ?

What is your way of Web App developing ?

Comment: Somewhat offtopic for SO

Comment: This question is way too broad for stackoverflow. But yes. websockets can give you very low latency. I've used them a lot. See my site www.rogueshell.com for example. Maybe also see: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/11/17/my-favorite-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really the place for questions like this, but I will give you a few brief pointers.

1. AJAX requests *shouldn't* take long, if they are consistently being slow then the problem is most likely your server-side code and inefficiencies there. Websockets aren't going to give you any benefit over AJAX if your server is slow.
2. A common design is to load the minimal dataset required for the page to function, AJAXing any other required data to get the page responsive as quickly as possible.
3. Caching and pre-fetching are great ways to speed up your site, for instance: if you are running a mysql query over and over, run it once and put the results in a caching service like memcached or mongodb with an expiration of an hour (or something) and serve the cached response, this will speed up your server response times. Pre-fetching is anticipating what your user is going to do next and loading that data in the background without any user interaction.
4. Consider using localStorage or IndexedDB if your users are loading the same data repeatedly